# 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: in /var/www/magento1/app/Mage.php:595

Tags: magento

I got this exception in log file when just create a simple hello world module.

```
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: MyCompanyName_HelloWorld_Block_Helloworld' in /var/www/magento1/app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/magento1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
#1 /var/www/magento1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('helloworld/hell...', Array)
#2 /var/www/magento1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('helloworld/hell...', 'helloworld.hell...')
#3 /var/www/magento1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('helloworld/hell...', 'helloworld.hell...')
#4 /var/www/magento1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 /var/www/magento1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#6 /var/www/magento1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#7 /var/www/magento1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#8 /var/www/magento1/app/code/local/MyCompanyName/HelloWorld/controllers/IndexController.php(5): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout()
#9 /var/www/magento1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): MyCompanyName_HelloWorld_IndexController->indexAction()
#10 /var/www/magento1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#11 /var/www/magento1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#12 /var/www/magento1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#13 /var/www/magento1/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#14 /var/www/magento1/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#15 {main}
```

config file etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyCompanyName_HelloWorld>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </MyCompanyName_HelloWorld>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <helloworld>
                <class>MyCompanyName_HelloWorld_Block</class>                
            </helloworld>
        </blocks>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <helloworld>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>MyCompanyName_HelloWorld</module>
                    <frontName>helloworld</frontName>
                </args>
            </helloworld>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <helloworld>
                    <file>helloworld.xml</file>
                </helloworld>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>    
</config>
```

layout file helloworld.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<layout version="0.1.0"> 
    <helloworld_index_index>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
        <!--<block type="core/template" name="helloworld" template="helloworld/helloworld.phtml"/> -->
            <block type="helloworld/helloworld" name="helloworld.helloworld" template="helloworld/helloworld.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </helloworld_index_index> 
</layout>
```

Block class file HelloWorld.php

```
class MyCompanyName_HelloWorld_Block_HelloWorld extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {

}
```

controlers/ indexController.php

```
class MyCompanyName_HelloWorld_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {
    public function indexAction() {
        //echo "We're echoing just to show that this is what's called, normally you'd have some kind of redirect going on here";
        $this->loadLayout();        
        $this->renderLayout(); 
    }
}
```

app/etc/module MyCompanyName_HelloWorld.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
     <modules>
        <MyCompanyName_HelloWorld>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </MyCompanyName_HelloWorld>
     </modules>
</config>
```

Please tell me where i missed the things in it. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amit Bera is on a right track. However his answer is not fully true. Class and file name can contain upper case letter, but then this letter should be upper case in layout too. The first letter of the class name is an exception - it is always upper case in class name and lower case in layout.

In your case if class name is HelloWorld, so block type in layout should be helloworld/**helloWorld** like this:

```
<block type="helloworld/helloWorld" name="helloworld.helloworld" template="helloworld/helloworld.phtml"/>
```

Comment: I had the same issue recently where my dev environment didn't care about the case for some reason and when I placed it into my test server, this issue crept up. Now if only I knew why my VM doesn't care about the case.

Answer (score 1):

Chetan,your `block class name is wrong` :

it Should be `Helloworld.php instead of HelloWorld.php.`

```
W should be small letter
```

According magento ,if any class file have two upper letter in file name if should explit into one dir and one file.

example

```
 In MyCompanyName_HelloWorld_Block_HelloWorld  the class name after 

MyCompanyName_HelloWorld_Block is Hellword,Magenti split class 
into Hello is dir Word the class file
```

Comment: thanks amit 
just i want to ask one more small thing that my block class name 'MyCompanyName_HelloWorld_Block_HelloWorld' is correct or not or it should be "MyCompanyName_HelloWorld_Block_Helloworld" ?
I just change my php filename HelloWorld to Helloworld

Comment: MyCompanyName_HelloWorld_Block_Helloworld is right.Block class name is depepnds on file name